# Reverse lastIndexOf

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little question which I don't find any documentation about it (or it doesn't exist, or I'm searching in a wrong way..)
I have an ID which I want to get the whole string before the last character I choose.

In this case:

```
str_stringId = "AB_generalForm_DateTime_calendar";
str_dateId = str_firstId.substring(str_firstId.lastIndexOf("_") +1);
```

In this case, str_dateId returns "calendar", but I want the whole string behind it. 
Is there a way to reverse this operation or do I need to count the number of letters of the whole string and then subtract with the length of "str_dateId" and after that, substring with the result?

Thank you.

Comment: how about `str_firstId.substring(0, str_firstId.lastIndexOf("_") );`

Comment: Thats pretty much it. It means I was searching the wrong way... Could you make a answer so that I would mark as correct? And thank you btw.

Comment: it's OK - Sergiu wasn't far behind me, and he explained the answer, so give him the reps :p

Comment: Alright, thank you again :)

Comment: Are you asking for the whole string before or behind that character? Your question states both.

Comment: Isn't that the same...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition is `string.substring(start,end)` so you can simply

`str_dateId = str_firstId.substring(0, str_firstId.lastIndexOf("_"));`